# Let $\rm R$ be the relation on the set $A$:

Tags: set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $A = \{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12\}$.

(1) Let $\rm R$ be the relation on the set $A$ defined as follows:

$∀a,b ∈ A, a\rm Rb$ $\iff$ every prime number that divides $a$ is a factor of $b$. Explain why the relation $\rm R$ is not a partial
order relation.

(2) Let $\rm R$ be the relation on the set $A$ defined as follows: $∀a,b ∈ A, a\rm Rb$ $\iff$ every prime number that divides $a$ is a factor of $b$ and $a ≤ b$. The relation $\rm R$ is a partial order
relation (you do not need to prove this). Draw the Hasse diagram for $\rm R$.

I found this question in my tutorial sheet, and I was unsure how to begin. From my understanding, a partial order relation is a relation that is Reflexive, Antisymmetric, and Transitive, and Im pretty sure I could do part(1). For part (2) im not quite sure how to go about drawing a Hasse diagram for the relation $\rm R$. Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Start from the definition: [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #2: observe that $2$ is related to all the elements in the set $\{2,4,6,8,10,12\}$. Likewise $3$ is related to all the elements in the set $\{3,6,9,12\}$ and $9$ is related to $\{9,12\}$ because $3$ is the only prime that divides $9$ and $3 \mid 12$ and so on.

The Hasse diagram mainly exhibits the direct relationship between two elements (loops for reflexive and edges coming out of transitivity are dropped). So

[image]